# Return prime numbers

Tags: python

The function should return a list of prime numbers between m and n. If m and/or n are prime numbers, they should also be included in the list.

Here's what I have done:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzRyC.png)

Here's the output that is supposed to be:
Please ignore the first two output as I have done them.
[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGKKa.png)

Comment: Please do not post images of your code. Edit your question and paste the actual code in the question and use the code formatting tools to structure it accordingly. Also, paste your output as text as well.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @idjaw Because I don't know how to format my code and post it, that's why I screenshot as a picture.

Comment: @hpotter054 It is pretty well explained when you are creating your question. The page guides you on how to properly write a question. Here is a meta question to help you in the future. I suggest editing your current question so it is better received: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit (30000)

"""The checkprime function uses the prime factor theorum to determine if a number is prime by checking it against a list of
prime numbers and ensuring it is not divisible by said numbers, therefore ensuring it is a prime, it requires a list of all prime numbers
smaller than the number being checked itself"""

def checkprime(primelist,value,recursions):
    #Decrease the index that is being looked at
    recursions -= 1
    #If the prime is not on 
    if recursions == -1:
        return(True)
    if value%primelist[recursions] == 0:
        return(False)
    return(checkprime(primelist,value,recursions))

'''The compileprimes function returns a list of all the prime numbers below the maximum value, using a list of primes,the function starts with a list of the first few prime numbers as a 
default value and works up from there, its start value is naturally set to the following prime to avoid unneccesary checks'''
def compileprimes(Up_To,primelist=[2,3,5,7],start=11):
    #Base case: If the value to compare is greater than the maximum value return the list of primes
    if start > Up_To:
        return(primelist)
    
    #Use the checkprime function to check if the 'start' value is a prime
    if checkprime(primelist,start,len(primelist)):
        #If the 'start' value is prime, append it to the list of primes
        primelist.append(start)
    #Increase by two to skip all even numbers
    start += 2
    
    #Recursive step
    return(compileprimes(Up_To,primelist,start))
```

The compileprimes function will recursively create a list of prime numbers up until and below the number you enter.
eg.

```
'''
>>> compileprimes(23)
[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,23]

'''
```

An issue you may encounter is that the `primelist` array may have to be assigned to the default upon calling the function again, however this method is considered to be much more efficient than the solution presented before as it does not divide by any non-prime numbers (which themselves are products of prime numbers), it also should work much faster than the previous example.
It is easy enough to remove any numbers under the n-value, so I'll leave that to you

Answer (score -2):

```
def primes(m, n):
    list_of_primes = []        # Keep track of primes
    for num in range(m, n + 1):    # make inclusive of upper bound
        is_prime = True            # Assume number is prime as starting condition
        for i in range(2, num):    # Check remainder from number 2 up to num
            if num % i ==  0:
                is_prime = False   
                break
        if is_prime and num > 1:          #EDIT HERE
            list_of_primes.append(num)   #add to the list of primes if True
    return list_of_primes
```

Note there are multiple ways to improve this algorithm, such as not checking even numbers ect, but this fits the criteria defined in your question.